# PolylineF draw a straight line between the points In addition to path

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, direction, react-google-maps

I use PolylineF from @react-google-maps/api to draw polygon on map.I have some points and I compute the path in  route function from google.maps.DirectionsService(). when the first time of the drawing after the map is loaded I accept two polygons between the points one it's OK acoording by DirectionsService but the second is worng it's a drawing of straight lines between the points.
It's occures only in the first time after loading the other times the drawing is excellent

here is my code:

```
const PolygonOnMap = ({ markpoints, close, remove, getPoints, readOnly, ss }) => {
    const { isLoaded } = useContext(GoogleMapAPIContext)
    const [points, setPoints] = useState([])
    const [, setDirRender] = useState(null)
    const dirService = useMemo(()=>{
        console.log('useMemo',isLoaded);
        if(isLoaded)
            return new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
        return null;
    },[isLoaded])


    const drawPolygon = async (markpoints) => {

        setPoints([])

        for (let i = 0; i < markpoints.length - 1; i++) {
            if (dirService) {
                try {
                    const result = await dirService.route({ origin: markpoints[i], destination:      markpoints[i + 1], travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING })
                    let newPoints = result.routes[0].overview_path.map(p => ({ lat: p.lat(), lng: p.lng() }))

                    setPoints(prev => [...prev, ...newPoints])
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message)
                }
            }
            
        }
       
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        drawPolygon(markpoints)
    }, [markpoints])


    return <>
        <div>
            {markpoints.map((p, i) => <MarkerF key={i} position={p} index={i} />)}
            {<PolylineF
                path={points}
                geodesic={true}
                options={{
                    fillColor: "red",
                    strokeColor: "#ff2527",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.75,
                    strokeWeight: 2,

                }}
            />}

        </div>
    </>
}

export default PolygonOnMap
```

And I'll attach screenshot below as well
the map with the multiple polygons:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpqTc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiple polygons only in the loading beacuse the component is render twice in react on development mode so when delete the strictMode tags in index.js page
like this:

```js
// <StrictMode>
        <App />
// </StrictMode>
```

the problem is solved